# Search websites whose urls contain a specific word

Tags: search, google-search, special-characters

I'm wondering if it's possible to search all the websites whose url contains a specific word.

Example: I'd like to search all the websites with the word ".uni??" in their url ("?" is the special character which means any character). A possible result of the above research could be the websites whose url contains the words .unibo or .unisi or .unife etc.

Comment: `inurl:` https://ahrefs.com/blog/google-advanced-search-operators/

Comment: Hello @Gantendo thank you very much for your comment. I think I misspoke. My goal is to search standard words (inside the websites) AND partial words in the websits' url: e.g. omero ".uni??", where omero should be inside the website and ".uni??" in the url.